# Why does my handleChange function cause lag in typing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This handleChange function is working as I want it to, but it causes a lag in typing.  I'm assuming it's to do with the `setTimeout` function. Is there a way to get rid of the lag, or at minimize it to where it's not noticeable? It's not workable as is.

If I remove the code from the handleChange method, the lag goes away.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const targetName = e.target.name;
    const targetValue = e.target.value;

    this.setState((state) => {
      clearTimeout(this.state.editingTimeout[targetName]);
      return {
        editing: false,
        editingTimeout: {
          ...state.editingTimeout,
          [targetName]: setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`${targetName}: ${targetValue}`);
            this.setState({
              [targetName]: targetValue,
            });
          }, 300),
        },
      };
    });
  };
```

Comment: Wonder why would you timeout on edit

Comment: With the `setTimeout`, you're delaying the actual change of the input value.

So if you type 'h', then a function that changes the value to 'h' is scheduled in 300ms.

Any change events you create within that 300ms will not include the 'h', because the value hasn't been changed yet. So 300ms after the last letter you type, the value of the input will change to that last letter.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  What I'm trying to do, is as they type, change what is seen in the text field in real time... but then once they stop typing for a a little, autosave that value.  Having a hard time making that work.

Answer (score 0):

You adding a timeout on each keystroke, you should [debounce](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) this action:

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'

...
onClick={debounce(this.handleChange, 500)}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Gives me an error about synthetic events and "cant' read propery name of null"